# Kafka Cluster showing continuous logs "INFO [SocketServer] Failed authentication (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)"

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 3 nodes of Kafka cluster in the Windows environment. I have recently added security to this existing cluster with the SASL_SSL mechanism.

Here is my server.properties security configurations on each node:

```
authroizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=

ssl.truststore.location=kafka-truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=******
ssl.keystore.location=kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=******
ssl.key.password=******
```

Everything is working fine. I am able to store and retrieve messages. Kafka stream applications are properly connected. But from yesterday I am getting continuous logs on all three nodes as

```
INFO [SocketServer brokerId=2] Failed authentication with host.docker.internal/ip (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

As the log says broker with id 2 is refusing the SSL handshake from the other brokers i.e. 1 & 3.
I have verified the jks certificates and they all are valid.
Did anyone know the reason for such logs?

Comment: I assume everything still works fine, right? (given that it is also reported as `INFO`). One way to try and find more about this is to change log level to `verbose` for these particular logs: `export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose"`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is an issue with the client's certificate. It might be expired or not contain the whole certificate chain. Add the following to your `log4j.properties` if you want to keep the messages but don't want it clogging up your server.log

```
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/ssl-handshake.log
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sslHandshakeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector=INFO, sslHandshakeAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector=false
```